# Prove that a Surface is regular

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

> Let $S$ be a surface parametrized by $$r:\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$$
> Let $p\in S$ be any point and $T_{p}S$ be the tangent plain passing through $p$. Let $v\in T_{p}S$ such that $||v||=1$, and let $H_{v}$ the plane passing through $p$ and parallel to $v$ and $N(p)$, where $N(p)$ is the unitary vector orthogonal to $p$. Prove that, in a neighborhood $V$ of $p$, $H_{v}\cap S$ is a regular surface.

I though about a function $$f:\mathcal{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(y):=⟨r(y)-p,v\wedge N(p)⟩$$ so I can study the critical point and I can caracterize the set of $w\in H_{v}\cap S$, but honestly I don't know to proceed with this way. Can soneone help me? Thanks before!

Comment: The statement is incorrect. The intersection will be a smooth curve near $p$. (This is a normal slice of $S$, something studied in elementary differential geometry.) It's very hard to know what you know and what you do not know. Do you know that the transverse intersection of two smooth surfaces is a smooth curve? Do you know that the preimage of a regular value is a smooth submanifold?